# Direction and position usage

Tags: expressions

Why do so many speakers and writers refer to the 'left-hand side' or 'right-hand turn'?  What function does the addition of'hand' provide to the direction?

Comment: The opposite of *right-hand* is *left-hand*. The opposite of *right* is *wrong*.

Comment: Less commonly, perhaps, the opposite of the *left[over] side* could be the side [of bacon, or whatever] that was ***eaten*** (or otherwise removed from the context).

Answer (score 2):

The modifier "hand" provides additional clarity in position or direction.

For example, if told to put a label on the "right" side of a document, that could be misconstrued to be the "correct" side of the document and open to interpretation.

If told to put the label on the "right-hand side" of the document, there is much less room for error.

https://jakubmarian.com/right-side-vs-right-hand-side-in-english/

Comment: That doesn't explain anything about the left hand ;)

Comment: Symmetrical consistency is important.  ;-p

Comment: I suppose that we could also speak of Bar Sinister and Bar Dexter, but at this point I am merely heading off the bar.  :0